# Plot command does not work in MatLab code

Tags: matlab, plot, simulation

I am working on a code which aims to plot the temperature of a hot water storage along the tank. The code is as follows:

```
Th = 50; % Hot Temperature (C)
Tc = 20; % Cold Temperature (C)
Tave = (Th+Tc)/2; % Average Temperature (C)
mf = 0.01; % Mass Flow Rate (kg/s)
H = 1.77; % Tank Height (m)
Dtank = 1.2; % Tank Diameter (m)
Dpipe = 0.05; % Inlet Pipe Diameter (m)
visc = 0.00070057; % Average Fluid Viscosity (m2/s)
rhoH = 987.68; % Hot Water Density (kg/m3)
rhoC = 997.78; % Cold Water Density (kg/m3)
rho = 0.5*(rhoH + rhoC); % Average Fluid Density (kg/m3)
k = 0.62614; % Thermal Conductivity (W/mK)
cp = 4068.5; % Specific Heat Capacity (J/kgK)
beta = 0.00032452; % Thermal Expansion Coefficient
% (1/K)
alfa = k/(rho*cp); % Diffusivity (m2/s)
g = 9.81; % Gravitational Acceration
% (m/s2)
N = 100; % Number of Nodes
delt = 1; % Time Step Size (s)
tTotal = 7200; % Total Simulation Time (s)
NumDiff = 1; % Activate Numerical Diffusivity (0 = OFF, 1 = ON)
Q = mf/rho; % Volumetric Flow Rate (L/min)
Ac = (pi/4)*(Dtank^2); % Tank Cross-section area (m2)
u = mf/(rho*(pi/4)*(Dtank^2)); % Mean Flow Velocity (m/s)
uIN = mf/(rhoH*(pi/4)*(Dpipe^2)); % Inlet Pipe Velocity (m/s)
x(1:N,1) = (H/(2*N)):(H/N):(H-H/(2*N)); % Node Locations
tEND = (tTotal/delt)+1; % Final Time Step Number
t(1:tEND,1) = 0:delt:tTotal; % Simulation time at each step(s)
if u == 0
C(1:tEND,1) = H/2; % Location of thermocline (no fluid flow) (m)
else
C = u*t; % Location of thermocline with time (w/ fluid flow) (m)
end
alfa = alfa + NumDiff*0.5*u*(H/N);
for i = 1:tEND
   for j = 1:N
      if x(j,1) > C(i,1) % Below Thermocline
          T(i,j) = Tave + (Tc-Tave)*erf((x(j,1)-C(i,1))/sqrt(4*alfa*t(i,1)));
      elseif x(j,1) < C(i,1) % Above Thermocline
          T(i,j) = (Tc + Th) - (Tave +(Tc-Tave)*erf((C(i,1)-x(j,1))/sqrt(4*alfa*t(i,1))));
      end
   end
end
figure(1)
plot(x(1:N,1),T(i,j))
title('temperature profile along the tank: Ideal Analytical Model')
xlabel('Tank Depth(m)')
ylabel('Temperature(°C)')
```

The issue is that the plot command does not show the diagram in the plot box although the axes ranges are correct. I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. This code errors because there are undefined variables.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks for your comment. I edited my code to produce the error.

Comment: The plot runs fine. You are only plotting 1 point: `T(i,j)` perhaps you wanted `T(somevalue,1:N)`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, I would like to plot temperature of the tank along the tank depth during the mentioned simulation time, but not a single point of time. I think I need to edit the plot command.

Comment: Then, change the code so it does not plot as single point. You have 7201 plots, so you may want to eiher use a different plotting mechanism (e.g. `surf`) or just chose one as I mentioned before

Comment: e.g. `surf(T,'edgecolor','none')` does something nicer.

Comment: Yes, it works. The tank height is specified `H = 1.77; % Tank Height (m)` . What if I want to plot `T` (temperature) versus Tank Height?

Comment: I'm here to help you understand how to do it, but not write it for you. If you have some particular question about how to use the fucntions that its not in the docs, please do ask, but no before you give it a try.